# Sorting images or radio buttons jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a table with jQuery with 3 radio buttons and images in one cell.

Like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="46" value="a" checked="checked" onfocus="updateStatus('46', 'a')" /><img src="/jwz/images/icons/a.png" name="a" alt="a" />
<input type="radio" name="46" value="d" onfocus="updateStatus('46', 'd')" /><img src="/jwz/images/icons/d.png" name="d" alt="d" />
<input type="radio" name="46" value="w" onfocus="updateStatus('46', 'w')" /><img src="/jwz/images/icons/w.png" name="w" alt="w" />
```

But I can't sort the column on checked radio button. A hidden input field doesn't work
Is there a way to make this work? E.g. with an invisble character or something?

Comment: What exactly do you want to sort? The 3 buttons in the cell or the whole table? Btw, the name attribute of the input element should start with a letter (http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id).

Comment: I want to sort on the value of the checked checkboxes. Like all cells where checkbox 'a' is checked, followed by cells where 'd' is checked, followd by cells whith checked 'w'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you use the [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) plugin for jQuery, you can sort on that column like this:

```
$("#yourTable").tablesorter({
    textExtraction: function(node) {
        return $('input:checked', node).val() || node.innerHTML;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution, using James Padolsey's simple [element sorting](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/) function,

```
$('#yourTable tbody tr').sortElements(function(a, b) {
    return $('input:checked', a).val() > $('input:checked', b).val() ? 1 : -1;
});
```